# Am I responsible for handling when a user clicks a button quickly/repeatedly?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-networking

As an Android developer, am I responsible for handling the situation where a user mashes a button quickly and repeatedly? Or is this considered user abuse? Nothing bad happens from a data standpoint on the backend.

I have a button that when selected makes a server call. Once the server responds, an activity is spawned from the returned message (using the handler). In some instances, if a user mashes the button repeatedly, duplicate activities can start stacking and can make for a bad user experience (i.e. user may need to hit the back button multiple times to return to a previous screen)

**Edit**:
I left out a few details. Right now a <strike>spinner</strike> dialog is being displayed while waiting for the server response. This intercepts all clicks. The problem is that in some instances the time between dismissing the spinner and starting the new activity is long enough for users to make more clicks.

Right now I am disabling the buttons, but it seems like <strike>a bit of a hack</strike> there could be a better solution.

Comment: This would be better suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could disable the button for a specific amount of time, thus not allowing the "user abuse".

Comment: define 'user abuse' ? from your own experience, it appears you have already realized you are responsible for making sure the interactions are available to the user only when they are relevant.

Comment: Updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> am I responsible for handling the situation where a user mashes a button quickly and repeatedly?

Typically yes.

> Or is this considered user abuse?

The user's opinion is what matters, and the user may not consider this to be "abuse" of your app.

> Once the server responds, an activity is spawned from the returned message (using the handler). I

Do not start an activity after a delay like this, particularly since the server may never respond.

> In some instances, if a user mashes the button repeatedly, duplicate activities can start stacking and can make for a bad user experience (i.e. user may need to hit the back button multiple times to return to a previous screen)

So, in other words, your UI is causing the user to get frustrated. The solution is to write a better UI.

Comment: Updated to clarify some things

Comment: @loeschg: "Right now I am disabling the buttons, but it seemed like a bit of a hack" -- well, Web sites/apps do that, so it's not *that* hacky. However, there is still a window of time between `setEnabled(false)` is called and when it takes effect, and so you might still get a couple of click events.

Comment: Agreed on the disabling comment. Perhaps "hack" was a poor choice of word. Will the delay calling setEnabled(false) really be significant enough that click events would be registered? I haven't seen this to be the case. Also, do you mind expanding upon the "write a better UI" comment?

Comment: @loeschg: "Will the delay calling setEnabled(false) really be significant enough that click events would be registered?" -- yes. Other developers have run into it. It may be less likely on faster devices, though.

Comment: @loeschg:  "Also, do you mind expanding upon the "write a better UI" comment?" -- based on your original question, the user pressed a button, suffered an indeterminate delay with no feedback, then had the entire UI change by jumping to a new activity. That would be craptacular. Your update improves this a bit, assuming that by "spinner" you do not mean `Spinner` but some sort of conventional progress indicator, like a `ProgressBar`.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense and thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 5):

When you begin an operation that takes a long time to execute, it is better to show a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), then dismiss it when the task has completed.

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

...

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mProgressDialog.show();

...

mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using a dialog to indicate server progress right now. See my edits.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution `btn.setEnabled(false)` after the first press. Reenabling when required.

As far as your question goes:

> As an Android developer, am I responsible for handling the situation
>   where a user mashes a button quickly and repeatedly?

I'd say no, I believe the user is smart enough to realise that if they abuse the app, it may not perform as expected. Though you can obviously use your own techniques to eleviate this problem, should you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question, and I actually am doing this right now. Gave you a +1, but I'm hoping to find a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your intention is. Are you trying to disallow clicking it twice during the whole running process? Or do you want to disallow clicking it rapidly.

In the first case, just disable the button using `myButton.setEnabled(false);` after the first click.

If you want to disable it for a time span, use if and else on `OnClick`. Combine this with a waiting function.

Something like:

```
public void Sleeper() {
  myButton.setEnabled(false);
  wait(time);
  myButton.setEnabled(true):
}
```